# MapView markers get directions to Address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

I have a MapView that has a marker in my Android app. I set the location using

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(mName);
```

and it shows up as this in the MapView, which is expected. [image]

However, when I click the buttons on the bottom right, which are supposed to give me directions to the marker's location. I get the following:

[image]

Does anyone know how to make it so that when I get the directions to the marker, it shows up as the actual name of the address as opposed to a set of lat and long coordinates? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You might have to use reverse geocoding https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: The marker only accepts a Lat and Long though, so I'm kind of confused on how it can show an address as its location rather than coordinates. I originally get an address and then I geocode it to get its coordinates, which I then put into the marker already. The next step is to just get rid of it from displaying the coordinates when you launch google maps.